# jquery on change function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, xhtml

I have a xhtml page with header and detail part.the header include the filters and the detail include the data fetch from db according to the filter selected.
My requirement, my filter include a dropdown with 2 values suppose "A" and "B", So according to the selection i want to disable some other dropdown.

I have added below code snippet:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $('select').change(function() {
                    alert($(this).val());
                    if($(this).val() == "A"){
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1')).prop("disabled", true);
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1')).prop("disabled", false);
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1')).prop("disabled", false);
                    }else if($(this).val() == "R"){
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1')).prop("disabled", false);
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1')).prop("disabled", true);
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1')).prop("disabled", true);
                    }else{
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1')).prop("disabled", false);
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1')).prop("disabled", false);
                        $(document.getElementById('dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1')).prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                    })
                })
            </script>
```

this works fine for the first time. But when i click on apply to get the data, next time it does not work.

Please help!!

Comment: What does 'apply to get the data' do? Looks like it breaks your change event.

Comment: "$('select').on("change", "select", function() {...})" can you try like that. Also can you check browser console to see if there is any jscript errors.

Comment: In console there is no error

Comment: Apply button is there which will hit the backing bean to get the data according to the selcted filter...i think its breaking the change event..is there any other way to do thi

Comment: i tried $('select').on("change", "select", function()...its not working..its also not disable the field which was working before

Comment: any idea how it can be done

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This example does not seem complete. It would be good to add the HTML elements to your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a complete jQuery solution, this would look like the following.

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/hfqc4cz5/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>R</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input id="dataForm:listView:filterId:field10value1" />
  <input id="dataForm:listView:filterId:field4value1" />
  <input id="dataForm:listView:filterId:field6value1" />
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    var field10 = $('#dataForm\\:listView\\:filterId\\:field10value1'),
      field04 = $('#dataForm\\:listView\\:filterId\\:field4value1'),
      field06 = $('#dataForm\\:listView\\:filterId\\:field6value1');
    switch (selected) {
      case "A":
        console.log("A Selected.");
        field10.prop("disabled", true);
        field04.prop("disabled", false);
        field06.prop("disabled", false);
        break;
      case "R":
        console.log("R Selected.");
        field10.prop("disabled", false);
        field04.prop("disabled", true);
        field06.prop("disabled", true);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("'' Selected.");
        field10.prop("disabled", false);
        field04.prop("disabled", false);
        field06.prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

From https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ :

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^{|}~` ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

I have also used the `switch()` structure. It does the same thing yet I like it better as I can grow it in the future.

You will also see I used jQuery selectors versus the raw JavaScript method. I also pushed the jQuery objects into their own variables for ease of use.

Comment: It worked fine..now i have one more issue..i have a error popup which comes after apply filter..

Comment: Errror is not there...but the popup is not coming...can you please help me to get the jquery js which only contains onchange function..i dont want the remaining function..

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Got a screen shot?